# Using a Bash script to Input in word in a command

Tags: bash

I am trying to make a simple Bash script to run the *[nano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano)* command via Bash, so that I don't need to type `nano filename` every time. I just execute `./n` and I will be asked for entering a file name and I type the file name and done; the file should open using *nano*.

I'm trying this, but there is somewhere wrong:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Enter file name: "
read INPUT
echo "$INPUT" >> "$JD"

nano JD
```

Comment: Are you looking for `nano "$input"` ?

Comment: yes something along it.

Comment: Worked. nano $input

Comment: I also want to know how to make a simple progress bar in bash. For example 1% to 100%

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple.
This script will do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Enter file name: "
read FileName
touch $FileName
nano $FileName
```

Save as it like "nanoScript.sh". And open a terminal and write:

```
chmod +x nanoScript.sh
```

And you can this:  `./nanoScript.sh`

It will create a file and open it with *nano*.